# Insert sqlite record if not exists, with a unique constraint

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE students(
    firstname VARCHAR(64), 
    lastname VARCHAR(64), 
    essay LONGTEXT,
    UNIQUE(firstname, lastname) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
```

I want to insert a record - if it already exists, I just want to update it:

```
String firstname = "bob";
String lastname = "smith";
String essay = "foo";

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("firstname", firstname);
values.put("lastname", lastname);
values.put("essay", essay);

SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
db.insert("students", null, values);
```

Because I'm using "ON CONFLICT REPLACE", can I just rely on the insert() method to take care of both my cases: (1) the student entry does not exist, so insert (2) the student entry exists, so overwrite it.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the `replace` or `replaceOrThrow()` methods?

Comment: Yes you can. If firstname and lastname already exist that record will be replaced

Answer (score 0):

You must read documentation:

> The algorithm specified in the OR clause of an INSERT or UPDATE
>   overrides any algorithm specified in a CREATE TABLE. If no algorithm
>   is specified anywhere, the ABORT algorithm is used.

From [SQL As Understood By SQLite: ON CONFLICT clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)